# Laravel 4 PHP pagination inside view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I use PHP to load XML files. Can I paginate it through the view?

Here's the code I use. When I pull the names from the XML file, I need to paginate them. Could I use the laravels `->paginate();`
I use:

```
@extends('base')
@section('title', 'Monsters')
@stop
@section('main')

<div class="container">
  <div class="doc-content-box">

    <legend>Monsters</legend>


    <?php   

    $monstersdir = 'C:\Users\E1\Desktop\theforgottenserver-v0.2.15-win64console\Mystic Spirit\data\monster';   

    if(is_dir($monstersdir)) {   
      $list = simplexml_load_file($monstersdir.'\monsters.xml'); 

      ?> 
      <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-content">


      <tbody>
        <?php  
        foreach($list as $monster) {  
          if ($monster['name'] > null) {  
            echo '  
            <tr>  
            <td style=""><a href="">'.$monster['name'].'</a></td>  
            </tr>';  
          }  
        }  
      }
      else{
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="label label-important">Error parsing your Monsters XML file</span><br /><br /> Invalid path!</div> ';
      }  
      ?>  
    </tbody>

  </table> 

</div>
</div>

@stop
```

Any hints? It's really needed. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can create a paginator manually in Laravel by calling `Paginator::make()`. Invoke the method with 3 arguments, i.e: the items want to display, the total number of items, and how many of those items should be displayed per page. See the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination) for an example.